# 'config.h' file not found after moving the third-party folder

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Im having an issue with running my app in react native after trying upgrade react-native version.

The error show in Xcode 10:

```
 mkdir: third-party: Permission denied

 /Users/XXXX/New app/mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh: line 49: cd: third-party: No such file or directory
```

I had been trying to install the folder again by deleting the node_module clone from the project and return to the previous react-native version

**Update:**

after moving the third-party folder under node_module/react-native/script to node_module/react-native I'm getting different error

```
'config.h' file not found
```

Comment: Try to rename 'New app' to NewApp or New_app to remove the whitespace.

Comment: @FelixToo didnt work for me

Comment: Do you have pods?

Comment: @Reza yes I have

Comment: Also please show what is inside your pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, try to follow this solution:
Assuming you are starting at your projects root. You need to execute these commands in your terminal:

```
cd ios

rm -fr Pods

rm Podfiles.lock

pod install

cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4

sh ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh
```

ios-configure-glog.sh uses a relative path to ./configure. Then execute this:

```
./configure
```

Then Clear(command+k) and rebuild(command+R).

Let me know if it is working.:)

Comment: got this error after running your second command:

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)...


*By the way the folder Third-party should be under react-native or under react-native/script?

Comment: @JJRedikes: Ok, just execute the ./configure  there.

Comment: @JJRedikes: Updated the answer. You need to make the pod again.

Comment: @JJRedikes: the third party folder should be in react-native

Comment: @JJRedikes what happened when you executed  ./configure?

Comment: in my project i don't have third-party directory and even its not created after successfully running ios-install-third-party.sh command. Can anyone help.

Comment: @JJRedikes were you able to fix this? If so can you please post the solution? I am having the same problem as you... I have no third-party directory and after running the script the directory is not created...

Comment: @JJRedikes  If you have solved this, I just posted this question if you can please comment the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76314993/config-h-file-not-found-when-making-ios-build

Answer (score 1):

You should try this [solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14382#issuecomment-405472763)

I had the same issue and it worked for me!

Comment: This solution is good, but i don't have third-party directory in my node_modules/react-native directory.

Comment: even its not created after successfully running ios-install-third-party.sh command. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run `ios-install-third-party.sh` like:

`>$ node_modules/react-native/ios-install-third-party.sh` or

```
>$ node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh
```

depending on the location of `ios-install-third-party.sh`.

Check if directory was created:

`$ ls node_modules/react-native/` -- third-party directory present

You can then build the project on XCode

Comment: in my project i don't have third-party directory and even its not created after successfully running ios-install-third-party.sh command. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

**If any of these solution does not work, please check your project path.**

**Project path and/or directory names should not contain any space in its name or you can create project on Desktop or in Documents directory.**

**It solves this issue**