# config.h file not found when making IOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After running successfully the `pod install` command, I am having issue making the IOS build.

The following error occurs:

```
glog -> mutex -> config.h not found
```

I have no `third-party` folder in `../node-modules/react-native/` folder and when I run the script `ios-install-third-party.sh` nothing happens.

```
expo : "^43.0.0"
react-native: "0.64.3"
xcode version - Version 14.3 (14E222b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by downgrading the version of Xcode to 13.4. As it turns out the version of expo and react-native were too old for the latest Xcode version. After I did this downgrade, everything worked fine.